# Replacing Text using Regular Expression in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

I have the following text in Visual Studio Design View:

```
<% =Utility.CreateLabel("lblHeader_LP","Online Loan Application") %>
```

and I need to convert that text into the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHeader_LP" Text="Online Loan Application" runat="server"/>
```

I am not really sure how to accomplish that but thinking the following:

**Find:** `<% =Utility.CreateLabel("(*.)","(*.)" &>`

**Replace:** `<asp:Label ID="$1" Text="$2" runat="server" />`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I think Visual Studio accepts different kind of Regular Expression :

**Find:** `\<% =Utility\.CreateLabel\({:q},(:b)*{:q}\) %\>`

**Replace:** `<asp:Label ID=\1 Text=\2 runat="server" />`

Where `{:q}` means quoted-text for back-reference and `(:b)` means space or tab character.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx

Comment: yes - leave it to Microsoft to create (or buy and continue to use) a regular expression language unlike any other in their flagship IDE, which is designed to compile multiple languages which all use a regular expression syntax completely different from the IDE itself but identical to each other... grumble

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your find:

```
<% =Utility\.CreateLabel\("([^"]*)","([^"]*)"\) %>
```

Comment: Here is the answer. Thanks. Helped me save too much time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but didn't work for the Replace case. It finds the text but when coming to replacing, it didn't work so I used what Microsoft says mentioned in my answer.